# How can I add header search paths in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, openframeworks

Here's a screenshot of my Android Studio build output:

[image]

While the error message says "m_pd.h" file is not found, the file exists in the Project Files under `pure-data/src` folder.

I think I need to add `pure-data/src` to header search path so other source files can find the `m_pd.h` file.

How can I do this in Android Studio?

---

**ADDED:**

In xCode, I can easily add header search paths like the following:

[image]

How can I add header search paths in Android Studio?

Comment: How are you building? Typically you would add those paths in your CMakeLists.txt (if using cmake) or Android.mk (if using ndkBuild).

Comment: @Michael I only have `build.gradle`

Comment: Then how are you building your native code?

Comment: @Michael I don't know how things work in Android but I don't have `CMakeLists.txt` or `Android.mk` in my project folder. I'm using openFrameworks.

Comment: You should probably start by reading https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code

Answer (score 2):

Go to `CMakeLists.txt` file which must be located in your `app/src/main/cpp` directory and add this line:

```cpp
include_directories(core/myLib)
```

where `core/myLib` is an include path relative to `CMakeLists.txt` file location